# Select box with autocomplete is too slow

Tags: java, struts2

Select Box with autocomplete is too slow when it is loading more than 1000 entries.Is there any other way to load data into select box with less time delay.

```
<sj:select 
                href="%{remoteurl1}" 
                id="fstlvel" 
                formIds="formSelectReload" 
                onChangeTopics="reloadsecondlist" 
                name="firstLevelFltrtype" 
                list="fltrLst" 
                indicator="indicator"
                loadingText="Loading"
                loadMinimumCount="2"
                emptyOption="true" 
                autocomplete="true"
                selectBoxIcon="true"
            />
```

Comment: Use an autocompleter, with minimum 3 characters: a selectbox with 1000+ elements is a nightmare of usability. Also use JSON.

Comment: But i Need two options one is autocomplete when they typing characters and second one is, list all elements when they click select box icon.

Comment: Why a user would want to pick up values on a selectBox with 1000+ elements ? Take a small step back and look if the analysis can be changed a bit...